# Anime movie where the main character uses telekinesis to catch and reattach a fallen leaf to a tree

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, telekinesis

I saw this anime 20 - 30 years ago. It was probably made in the 80s or early 90s. It was a movie and it was dubbed.

Telekinesis is important in it. I remember specifically a scene where one of the main characters catches (with telekinesis) and reattaches a fallen leaf to a tree.

They were a kind of experiment or something; their whole world was inside some sort of facility and the stars overhead were lights. They try to escape from the facility through some kind of secret passage.

I think the main character was a male, youngish, with a female secondary character who was older (teenish maybe). No names I can remember. There was no sex or gore to my recollection. A portion of the characters had powers. Or maybe everyone does, but only a few can use them well or to good effect. It was magical to them (the characters), but I think that it was science based, like an experiment due to an outside force. Regarding the art style (and I'm not really sure on this, because it was so long ago), the people had realistic proportions, maybe along the lines of *Macross* or *Evangelion*.

I remember that the main character wasn't able to use telekinesis very well at the beginning, but at the climax could and was powerful. The female secondary character was a mentor more than a love interest. The characters were part of a program or training school with others who could use telekinesis (but not in a physical building). The ending has a lot of explosions.

The main character had short black hair.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: We don't know when you were young... Maybe you still are?

Comment: Is there any chance that you remember what decade this was in, whether you saw it on TV\DVD\VHS, and whether it was subbed or dubbed?

Comment: I saw it 20 - 30 years ago. It was probably made in the 80s or early 90s. It was dubbed.

Comment: @MattUser - Anything else you can [remember](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774)? Who were the main characters? Were they male or female? Were they young or old? What were there names? Was there a love interest? Was this intended for adults (with sex/gore) or kids? Did everyone have powers? Were those powers pseudo-scientific or straight-up magical? What was the art style? Were there any specific words used to describe how these powers work (e.g. "*shining*", "*psyching*", etc)?

Comment: Hmm.  I think the main character was a male, youngish with female secondary character who was older (teenish maybe). No names I can remember.  There was no sex or gore to my recollection.  A portion of the characters had powers.  Or maybe everyone does but only a few can use them well or to good effect.  It was magical to them (the characters) but I think that it was science based like an experiment due to an outside force.  Art style was (and I'm not really sure on this because it was so long ago) the people had realistic proportions maybe along the lines of macross or Evangelion.

Comment: Was this a movie or a series?

Comment: I do remember that the main character wasn't able to use telekinesis very well at the beginning but at the climax could and was powerful.  Female secondary character was a mentor more than a love interest.  The characters were part of a program or training school with others who could use telekinesis (but not in a physical building).  The ending has a lot of explosions.

Comment: It was a movie.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of any of the characters?

Comment: Main character short black hair. I know, not very helpful lol.

Comment: Can you [edit] these details into the main body, please? That way anyone wanting to help doesn't need to read every comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is ***[Mother: Saigo no Shoujo Eve](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1154/Mother__Saigo_no_Shoujo_Eve)*** (1993), also known as *E.Y.E.S. of Mars*.

From the [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1781):

> The students of the EYES have special psychic powers and are the last hope for a dying humanity on the planet of Mars. Deep under the land is where their school lies away from the pollution and mayham of the overly populated city above; in a vast forest. With memories of where they came from and everything about themselves gone; Eve must discover their missing pasts in order to build a new future.

A girl named Eve is a student at an all-girls boarding school situated in a lush forest on Mars. The girls are being taught to develop their "inner mind power," and have no memory of their lives prior to waking up in the forest, or knowledge of the world beyond the forest.

There's a scene early on in which Eve uses her powers to briefly catch and suspend a falling leaf in mid-air, though it continues its descent after a few seconds, as her mastery of her powers is still quite poor. Her mastery improves as the film progresses.

> [image: An image of Eve suspending a leaf in mid-air with her inner mind power.]

One night, while Eve is alone in her room, a boy named [Dew](https://myanimelist.net/character/113065/Dew) climbs through her window and tells her that he came down from the city where she used to live, and wants to take her back. He leads her to a cliff face at the edge of the forest, which they climb until they reach a ventilation duct embedded high up in the cliff face.

Dew explains that the entire forest is located underground, beneath a city on the surface of Mars, and that the night sky and stars visible from the forest are all manmade. They then climb through the air vent into a utility tunnel and use a high-speed elevator to travel up to the surface.

The relationship between the two main characters is platonic, there's no sex or gore in the film, and there are a number of explosions in the last ten minutes. I won't say why, as it'd spoil the plot beyond what's needed to show that this does mostly match your description.

You can watch the full film at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/mother-saigo-no-shoujo-eve), but here's a TV advert for it:

Comment: That seems like an excellent match.

Comment: Wow! That's it!  Thank you! How in the world did you figure it out?

Comment: @MattUser Be sure to upvote and accept this as the answer :)

Comment: @Matt User - I used Anime-Planet's search tool, with the 'Sci Fi' and 'Psychic Powers' tags, and filtered the years to 1980-2000. That brought up about 30 results, but _E.Y.E.S. of Mars_ stood out as one of the most likely candidates due to the promotional image (featuring a boy and girl with a forest in the background) and the synopsis. I then looked it up on YouTube to see if I could find the relevant scenes. I determined that it was a strong match within a few minutes, but ended up watching the whole thing at 1.25x speed, since the general premise of the story appealed to me.